# How can I use sumif with len and if statments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A client wants a clean way in Excel (no helper columns) to sum data in a table on another sheet based upon the project it's assigned to

They code their projects as 'aa 1.1 sap', 'aa 1.1 ar', 'aa 1.2',...,'aa 1.10', 'aa 1.11', etc.  Only the 1.1's have additional characters after, but they want to see all 1.1's, 1.2's, 1.10's etc. as a group.  I created a helper column to only pull the numbers out and used sumif on those, but they don't want that helper column (super frustrating since I can just hide it in the table).  I've tried various combinations of sumif with len and if statements with no luck.  They also don't want a pivot table.  Just a simple table with the project number (1.1, 1.2, 1.15) and the total next to that.  I'm also running into an issue with Excel confusing 1.10 with 1.1, but I should be able to figure that out.

```
Name    Amount  Type
proj13  42  it 1.1 sap
proj14  4444    it 1.1 sap
proj15  566565  it 1.1 ar
proj16  4566    it 1.1 ar
proj8   0.1 it 1.10
proj9   2646    it 1.2
proj10  6546    it 1.2
proj11  46451   it 1.13
proj12  77556   it 1.15
proj13  42  it 1.15
```

So, the helper column is in column D with the formula `=IF(IF(LEN(C2)=7,MID(C2,4,4),MID(C2,4,3))="1.10",1.01,IF(LEN(C2)=7,MID(C2,4,4),MID(C2,4,3)))`

(right now I'm cheating by turning 1.10 into 1.01)
This returns a column showing just the numbers in the project code

And the totals are using `=SUMIF(D:D,"="&K2,B:B)` where K is storing the values (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.) based upon the just the number

Totals should equal:

```
1.1     575617
1.10    0.1
1.2     9192
1.13    46451
1.15    77598
```

I can get this with the helper column, but I cannot figure out who to get it all into one formula in one cell.  I'm trying to avoid VBA or macros since that's something they also don't want.

Comment: How do they feel about a UDF?

Comment: Should be doable with SUMIF and wildcards.

Comment: The problem is distinguishing `1.1` from `1.10` and `1.11`

Comment: Look for `1.1 ` - with a space after it.

Comment: Yes, but I notice `proj9` has `1.2` at the end of the string. A good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful here

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad note from OP that "only the 1.1's have additional characters after."

Comment: Regardless of the technical details of the question, to me it is silly to have a requirement that helper columns are not allowed. Helper columns are very useful both for increased efficiency and easier understanding of formulas. I would talk to your client and tell them that this is a foolish requirement.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, but it implies `1.1` may be at the end of the string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad maybe not, up to OP to clarify whether "only the 1.1's have additional characters after" implies that all 1.1's have following characters. I took that to mean they all do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` and wildcards.

For the special case of `1.1`, use a space + wildcard:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"*"&E2&" *",B:B)
```

For all other cases:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"*"&E3,B:B)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a single formula, one would need to change to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&E2&" "," "&$C$2:$C$11&" ")),$B$2:$B$11)
```

[image]